# Detect Android User Location

Tags: android, gps, location, google-play-services, locationmanager

I'm trying to find a solution to detect my android app user location without using the GPS.

I'm getting the user location in two different ways, the first one is using the android **LocationManager** for some devices such as Samsung S2 and Samsung Note 4 this following instruction returns false:

```
 isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

Also, I tried to get the location using Google-play-services, for those devices the **onLocationChanged** is never called.

Is there a way to determine the location without enabling the GPS? 
How does Foursquare do that? It never asks the user to open/enable the GPS?

Thanks,

Comment: TowerLocation can give you the result (not much accurate), but you need an active SIM in the phone for that.

Answer (score 0):

Fused location provider in android, manages the underlying location technology and gives you the best location according to your needs and available sensors (if gps is disabled it uses others)

You could try LastLocation instead of onLocationChanged,

```
...
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
        mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
    }
}
```

[Getting las known location Android](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#last-known)

Comment: Or using this library to avoid having to deal with Google API client setup: https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation